# Context Managers with cx_oracle and passing SQL to function

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle, contextmanager

I am running into a bit of problems when trying to use a context manager to open a connection to my primary write connection to pass a tuple of bind variables to update values to in a query.

I want to use the below code to setup my connection, pass a query to it, use bind variables i am passing from a list of tuples to perform an executemany, then close the connection.

I am having problems with it identifying the update function in my class to pass the SQL query and bind variables too, getting a "cannot find reference to None" error. I am a bit stuck on what to do from here or what I am doing wrong. Any assistance is much apperciated.

```
import cx_Oracle 
import pandas as pd

class PrimaryConnection:

    def __init__(self, primary_connection):
        self.primary_connection = primary_connection
        self.db_conn = None
        self.db_cursor = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.db_conn = self.primary_connection
        self.db_cursor = self.db_conn.cursor()


    def __exit__(self, *args):
        try:
            self.db_cursor.close()
            self.db_conn.close()
        except AttributeError:  # isn't closable
            print('Could not close connection')
            return True  # exception handled successfully

    def update(self, sql, bind):
        self.db_cursor.executemany(sql, bind)
        self.connection.commit()
        self.db_cursor.close()

def get_primary_connection():
    return cx_Oracle.connect(f"{os.environ.get('DB_USERNAME')}", f"{os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD')}",
                                   "domain", encoding="UTF-8")


data_to_update = [(322, 433), (555, 222)]

with ReplicaConnection(get_replica_connection()) as replica:
    replica.update('''update corp_acct set name = :x where corp_acct_nbr = :y ''', data_to_update)
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to resolve this a different way doing this

```
class DbConnection:

    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection
        self.cursor = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        return self.cursor

    @timeout()
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        try:
            self.connection.commit()
            self.cursor.close()
        except TimeoutError:
            self.connection.rollback()
            self.cursor.close()
        except AttributeError:
            print('Could not close connection')
            return True

with DbConnection(dbx_connector.get_primary_connection()) as cursor:
            cursor.executemany("""
            UPDATE sales_quote
            SET status = :UPDATE_SQ_STATUS_TO
            WHERE sales_quote_id = :SALES_QUOTE_ID
            """, sales_quotes_to_update)
```